# target a class next to another class

Tags: css, datepicker

I have installed [datepicker.js](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and need to target a class that is together with another class. If I generally target the class `ui-state-disabled` it will obviously affect ALL `ui-state-disabled` however I need to target only the `ui-state-disabled` that is together with `ui-datepicker-prev`

```
<a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled ui-state-hover ui-datepicker-prev-hover" title="Prev"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span></a>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Pick up a real basic CSS tutorial and learn the basic selectors and how to combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target same element that has multiple classes like this:

```css
.ui-state-disabled.ui-datepicker-prev {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-state-disabled ui-datepicker-prev">prev</div>
<div class="ui-state-disabled">Page 1</div>
```

Hierarchy of elements (parent has class `a`, child has class `b`):

```css
.a .b {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  some text
  <div class="b">
    another text
  </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about that [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can just select them together:

```
.ui-state-disabled.ui-datepicker-prev
```